# Use of unresolved identifier 'referenceWithThreadConfined'

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety, realm

While working in an iOS project, I am using pod 'Realm' (not pod 'RealmSwift'). I am trying to use `RLMThreadSafeReference` discussed in post in section :[Passing instances across threads](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/). I want to write my new code like `let personRef: RLMThreadSafeReference = RLMThreadSafeReference.referenceWithThreadConfined(person)` in swift using pod library 'Realm'. I can not move to pod library 'RealmSwift' because my project's other modules are using pod library 'Realm',

> Build error : Use of unresolved identifier 'referenceWithThreadConfined'

Note that, I have already added

```
 #import <Realm/Realm.h> 
 #import <Realm/RLMThreadSafeReference.h>
```

in Host apps bridging header.

I am using `Realm v4.1.1`. Anyone can help to find out the actual problem?

Comment: Are you asking about ThreadSafeReference, as in `let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)`?

Comment: @Jay, "let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)" is available in RealmSwift'. I want to write ThreadSafeReference in swift from pod library 'Realm'. I don't want to change my library because other modules are using 'Realm'.

Comment: It's pretty much the same function in both Swift and C. The ObjC function looks like this `RLMThreadSafeReference *personRef = [RLMThreadSafeReference
    referenceWithThreadConfined:person];`

Comment: RLMThreadSafeReference *personRef = [RLMThreadSafeReference referenceWithThreadConfined:person]; It works in ObjC code but I want to write my new code in swift. I can't write like "let personRef: RLMThreadSafeReference = RLMThreadSafeReference.referenceWithThreadConfined(person).

Comment: My first comment showed the Swift version of that same function. If you want to code in Swift then use that one. If you want ObjC, use the ObjC version. Can you clarify what you're trying to do and what you are asking as the question and comments are very confusing.

Comment: I want to write my new code like let personRef: RLMThreadSafeReference = RLMThreadSafeReference.referenceWithThreadConfined(person) in swift using pod library 'Realm'. I can not move to pod library 'RealmSwift' because my project's other modules are using pod library 'Realm'.

Comment: So you're saying you have a Swift Project back by a Realm ObjC pod file?